# Change value of materialize select box by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular-material

I want to change materialize select box value by jquery.

I am using `$('#myselect').val('1');` on `onchange` event of other select box but it not works.

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    $('#myselect').val('1');
});
```

Comment: Do you want to explain what exactly is happening? Do you have an error or can you reproduce on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Error is not coming and also value of select box not changing if i use material select box. But if i use browser select box it change easily.

Answer (score 33):

It appears to work fine for me, changing the first drop down, resets the value of the second drop down to 1.

I have done a rough implementation on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55r8fgxy/1/

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select id="myselect">    
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#select1").on('change', function() {
        $('#myselect').val("1");

        // re-initialize material-select
        $('#myselect').material_select();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using materialize select box not this, it is also working for me please use materialze css select box then you able to see what i have problem.http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Comment: Okay, I haven't used that - but I assume you will have to re-initialise the `#myselect` element after changing its value. `$("#myselect").material_select();`

Comment: Try all ways but not find any solution, because value changed in hidden select box not change in materialize select box.

Comment: Check the updated jsFiddle link above for a working solution - at least with the limited markup that has been provided.

Comment: If we use combo of jquery timepicker and select box then value of select box on change on  $('#time1').on('selectTime', function() {}): event

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. It seems you have deviated from the original question. Maybe time for another post?

Comment: Same code is not working for me, how we can know material_select() function works?

Comment: I just debug code and find that in fiddle ul li created by select boxes but not in my case.

Comment: Strange, I'm clicking the Fiddle yet not seeing the second box change value. Is this a bug in Materialize?

Comment: materializecss wraps select element in a div and ul-li. I am using this in my angularjs app. My ng-model (which I have placed on select element) is not data binding to the selected element. How can I capture the selected value when user selects an option from dropdown?

Answer (score 20):

```
$('#myselect').formSelect() ;
```

The new method is formSelect(), use this after you have updated the select.

Comment: Excellent answer. After `$('#myselect').val('');`, It worked after I added `$('#myselect').formSelect();`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 12):

As suggested by @logikal, you have got to re-Initialize

```
$("#myselect").material_select()
```

Answer (score 7):

In 2018 (`Materialize v1.0.0-rc.2`), first you have to set your option programmatically:

```
$('#SELECT-ID').find('option[value="SELECT-VALUE"]').prop('selected', true);
```

And then re-initialise the `select` input with:

```
$("#SELECT-ID").formSelect();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 6):

Rather than using .val(), it's cleaner to set value as usual with jQuery :

```
$('#my-select').find('option[value="my-value"]').prop('selected', true);
$("#my-select").material_select();
```

Comment: The first line works with materialize 1.0.0-Beta version. The `.material_select()` method is no longer an initialization method see [docs](https://materializecss.com/select.html).

Answer (score 6):

For a new materialize 1.0.0 use `.select()` instead of `.material_select()`

Solution without re-initialization.

```
function msValue (selector, value) {
 selector.val(value).closest('.select-wrapper').find('li').removeClass("active").closest('.select-wrapper').find('.select-dropdown').val(value).find('span:contains(' + value + ')').parent().addClass('selected active');
}
```

Then just use

```
msValue($("#select_id"), "value_here")
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Everything else would only work once then stop.

Answer (score 5):

This answer might be late but it might help someone else.

On Ready add the line below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').formSelect();
    });
```

Each time you change an option within your Select add the line below

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
    $('#myselect').val('1');
    $('select').formSelect();
});
```

This is what worked for me, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Using delegated event fixes the problem for me.

HTML

```
 <div class="input-field col s10" id="pickerContainer">
 <select>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```

JS

```
$('#pickerContainer').on('change', 'select', function(){
 console.log("got you");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Since JQuery is no longer a hard dependency of the Materialize library, one can easily update the select via the `init` static method with any of the lookup methods:

```
const reinitialize = (selector, value) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element.value = value;
    const {
      options
    } = M.FormSelect.getInstance(element); //pass through initialization options;
    return M.FormSelect.init(element, options);
  };
```

A quick runnable demonstration:

```js
(() => {

  const reinitialize = (selector, value) => {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element.value = value;
    const {
      options
    } = M.FormSelect.getInstance(element); //pass through initialization options;
    return M.FormSelect.init(element, options);
  };

  const interval = (callback, delay = 250) => {
    callback();
    setTimeout(interval, delay, callback, delay);
  };

  M.AutoInit(); //initializes everything

  interval(() => {
    const id = "test";

    const randVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

    reinitialize("#" + id, randVal);
  });

})();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select id="test">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

Here is a version of the above for JQuery (to be fair to other answerers - this is a generalized version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55730245/11407695)):

```
const updateSelect = (selector, value) => $(selector).val(value).formSelect();
```

Please, note that the actual core of every solution is (see [docs](https://materializecss.com/select.html)):

> you need to reinitialize the select component every time a value is updated non-natively

The rest depends on the version of Materialize used and whether one uses JQuery or not. It is also important to keep in mind that:

> `material_select()` solutions are outdated! Use `formSelect()` as of Materialize 1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to what logikal answered but I think is cleaner:

```
$(".your-component-class").change(function(){

   //your code..


   //re-initialize component
   $(this).material_select();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution in case it helps someone. I used a lot of what @Raold said.
the issue I had was the select was getting stuck when it's updated without the code below.

```
function updateSelect(value) {
    var select  =  $('#myselectId');
    $(select).val(value);
    var text = $(select).find(':selected').text();
    $(select).closest('.select-wrapper')
        .find('li').removeClass("active")
        .closest('.select-wrapper')
        .find('.select-dropdown').val(text)
        .find('span:contains(' + value + ')')
        .parent()
        .addClass('selected active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution, I used in my project:

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").addEventListener("change", function()
{
  console.log("Hello, World!")
});
```

I don't know if the event trigger gives you selected item or selected item's value - you can check it yourself!

Answer (score 0):

```
const selectObj = document.querySelector('#select');
selectObj.value = "new value";
const {
    options
} = M.FormSelect.getInstance(selectObj);
M.FormSelect.init(selectObj, options);
```