# Materialize CSS select: Get selected value when close

Tags: jquery, materialize

Trying to get selected value on Materialize CSS select element at close.

Something like this:

```
$('input.select-dropdown').on('close', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

just doesn't work, because shows last selected value. First time shows nothing, and next time shows selected value first time.

I supose this is because close action is declared before asign selected value.

Anyone knows if there is any way to get selected value on "close"?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I don't want to select value by jquery, I want to detect selected value (if any option has been selected) when dropdown close.

I'm trying to implement label funcionality for select as for text input: when select is opened, label goes smaller, and when select is closed, if no value is selected, returns to initial position.

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to get it on change? e.g. $('input.select-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
}).trigger('change');

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change value of materialize select box by jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341095/change-value-of-materialize-select-box-by-jquery)

Comment: On change doesn't work, and I need to get selected value on close. Not duplicated, because I don't want to change value of select programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I just add a different class to label when element in dropdown is clicked.

With this two classes ("active" from Materialize framework and "forced" asigned on selecting element) I can do what I want, label for select working like label of text input :)

[image: Materialize CSS select labeled]

Answer (score 0):

Use mouse down event.

```
$('input.select-dropdown').on('mousedown', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Or you can try with `change` event. here:

```
$('input.select-dropdown').on('change', function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Comment: Seems not working, show selected value when opening, instead when closing :(

Comment: @SamuelE.Cerezo, what do you think ?

Comment: Doesn't work with "change". :( Te purpose to detect close event is because I'm implementing label funcionality as text input. When select is opened, label goes up and smaller, when select is closed, if no option selected, label returns to initial position.