# resetting angular reactive form is not updating the select option

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have created an angular form using [materialize-css](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html). Here is the **HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="addFeedForm" (ngSubmit)="addFeed(addFeedForm.value)" class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col m6 s12">
            <select formControlName="departmentId" #feedDepartment>
                <option value=0>General</option>
                <option [value]="department.id" *ngFor="let department of departmentList">{{department.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <label>Department</label>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s3 offset-s5" (click)="resetAddFeedForm()">Reset</button>

            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!addFeedForm.valid" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s3 offset-s1">Add</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is how I have created the angular form

```
this.addFeedForm = new FormGroup({
      departmentId: new FormControl(0,Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
});
```

And when I submit I do

```
addFeed(data: any): void {
    console.log(data);

    this.addFeedForm.reset({    departmentId: 0    });
}
```

If I change the department select option to something else and submit and reset the form by setting `departmentId` to be 0 then "**General**" should be selected in the select option.

It is not updating on the UI but on the console, it sets departmentId to 0.

The UI behaviour is like
[image]

on the UI selected option is different but on the console departmentId is 0

**Update : This is the stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tchftw

Comment: Please provide a minimal stackblitz showcasing your problem if none of the existing answers solve your problem. The code you posted in your question seems to reset the UI correctly: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4degxv

Comment: This has to do with the way `materialize-css` works. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/q/30341095/9423231 for example. 2-way data binding doesn't seem to work and you'll have to do a lot manually. It might be easier to use the Angular Materialize wrapper [ngx-materialize](https://sherweb.github.io/ngx-materialize/home) if your whole UI is made with materialize.

Answer (score 1):

update your form control using

```
 addFeed(data: any): void {
     console.log(data);
     this.addFeedForm.patchValue({departmentId: '0'});
 }
```

Or you can also use

```
this.addFeedForm.controls['departmentId'].setValue('0');
```

Comment: both of the solutions are not working :(. same on UI selection is not getting updated but value of departmentId is set to 0

Comment: when you are setting the value of departmentId to make that value as a string because you are assigning a string value to departmentId

Comment: same not working variables are getting updated but no reflection on select option.. check the image i have added in question

Comment: make your option <option value="0">General</option> then try

Comment: @SunilGarg this.addFeedForm.get('departmentId').reset(); try this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/patch-with-form

Comment: this is more of materialize-css issue.. provided the stackblitz link in question

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
addFeed(data: any): void {     
   this.addFeedForm.patchValue({departmentId: [0]});
}
```

PatchValue will always works to re-set the value in angular. It always works for me.

Comment: same not working variables are getting updated but no reflection on select option

Comment: this is more of materialize-css issue.. provided the stackblitz link in question

Answer (score 1):

I am also face the same problem like above said, so I wish to share my workaround for the same

template

```
<select formControlName="departmentId" #feedDepartment>
    <option selected [ngValue]=null disabled >General</option>
    <option [value]="department.id" *ngFor="let department of departmentList">{{department.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

typescript

```
this.addFeedForm = this.fb.group({
  departmentId: [null,Validators.required]
})

onResetForm(){
this.addFeedForm.reset();
}
```

In reactive form: I initialize the departmentId formControlName with null, so i changed my first select option accordingly in template also. hence i got the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

put type reset on button it will work : `<button type="reset" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s3 offset-s5" (click)="resetAddFeedForm()">Reset</button>`
working example : [stackblitz live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/resetting-angular-reactive-form-is-not-updating-the-select-opti)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tchftw .. updated the question as well

Comment: Hey you need to put button type as reset on resetAddFeedForm() method. it will work.