# JQuery: SELECT does not show value after getJSON

Tags: jquery

I have a strange problem with jQuery. I have a form with a SELECT element.

```
<select id="category" name="category" class="validate" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>please select</option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

I want to set the value of the SELECT element like this:

```
$('#category').val('test');
```

That does work fine so far. SELECT shows the right value in my form.

But when I use it with getJSON SELECT does not show the value.

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
$.getJSON('getevent.php', { id: id }, function(event) {
  $('#category').val('test');
});
```

It is exactly the same code in both cases. The only difference is getJSON.

In both cases the value is set correctly. But in the second case the value is not shown in the form. The form only shows "please select".

I have really no idea, how to fix this.

Comment: `$(this).data('id')` implies it's within an event handler.  Does the value exist in your drop down *before* the code runs?

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @freedomn-m The id has nothing to do with that value.

Comment: @barmar No errors. I also checked values AFTER setting them with `console.log($('#category').val())`. Value was set correctly. But does not show.

Comment: Something else must be resetting the form after this. Are you sure the page isn't reloading? If you're calling the code from a submit button, that will submit the form and reload unless you use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. It is really strange. All other values in that form are shown correctly. Only SELECT is not shown in that second case. I really have no idea... By the way: It is a Materialize form. In both cases.

Comment: I know nothing about Materialize, so I don't know if it's relevant.

Comment: The thing is: I don't even know how to start debugging.

Comment: @wepli23 The thing is that your code inside the getJSON doesn't call. So you need to check that if you have data for your id or not. for DEBUGGING use a chrome console that mostly shows the errors, also the network tab is useful for requests. To validate that your getJSON is working fine don't think about the setting value for select as if your request is successful it will be called and working fine.

Comment: Thank you, @NasserAliKarimi. The example shown above is very short. The whole code is much longer. I have logged id, event and all other values in console. All fields of the form are filled with values as it should - except for the SELECT field. Even if I fill all values manually like `id = 183` or `event = 2`, the SELECT field does not show the value - alltough value is set correctly to `test`.

Comment: so if you select the select options manually it will have the result or not?

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi Yes, it has a result when I select is manually. It even has the right result, when it was filled with jQuery and not selected manually. But the field itself does not show that value in that second case. So it is definitely filled with the right value. But I do not understand, why the field does not show that value in the second case, but does in the first one.

Comment: *The id has nothing to do with that value* - clearly didn't read what I wrote.

Comment: @freedomn-m Maybe I got you wrong, sorry. Yes, its within an event handler. Clicking a buttons opens a modal with the form. The form is filled with data from that getJSON request. Therfore I do need the id. But even if I try to set the id manually `id = 183`, it does not work. What I do not understand: All other values are set and displayed correctly in the other input fields. Only the SELECT field ist **set** correctly but not **displayed** in that case. So I assume there must be any kind of interference between getJSON and showing the value. Without getJSON the value there is shown.

Comment: I got it! Sorry, it really was a materialize thing. I had to re-initialize select after setting that value. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341095/change-value-of-materialize-select-box-by-jquery) But strange, why it does work without re-initializing in the first case...

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a little example. This selects the second option with getJSON.

```js
// I don't now where this value come from.
//var id = $(this).data('id');
//
var id = 1;
$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bmehler/employees/main/employees', {
  id: id
}, function(event) {
  $('#category').val('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category" name="category" class="validate" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected>please select</option>
  <option value="test">test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! Basically this is what I did. I also tried to recreate my problem on JSFiddle - but it does work there in that simplified variant. So I am not shure, what to do. Is there some way to share the whole code with the real json and the real variables savely?